# How to explicitly specify the output's string length in numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy.vectorize to convert some integers to strings. But, it seems the output string is always limited to a maximum of 8 characters.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

In [3]: def num_str(num):
   ...:     return str[:num]
   ...: 

In [4]: np.vectorize(num_str)(np.arange(15))
Out[4]: 
array(['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'abcdefg',
       'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh',
       'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

I also tried specifying otypes explicitly but even then it doesn't seem to work.

```
In [5]: np.vectorize(num_str, otypes=["|S25"])(np.arange(15))
Out[5]: 
array(['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'abcdefg',
       'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh',
       'abcdefgh', 'abcdefgh'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

As of now, I am setting the otype as object and finally converting them to strings.

```
In [6]: np.vectorize(num_str, otypes=["O"])(np.arange(15)).astype('|S25')
Out[6]: 
array(['', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'abcdefg',
       'abcdefgh', 'abcdefghi', 'abcdefghij', 'abcdefghijk',
       'abcdefghijkl', 'abcdefghijklm', 'abcdefghijklmn'], 
      dtype='|S25')
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a known bug in Numpy: http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1892

Your workaround looks good.  You might want to ask on the Numpy mailing list or comment on the bug ticket.  It seems there's been no recent action toward fixing it.